# Building LINQ Dynamic Order Clause, But Cast Field

Tags: linq, dynamic, expression

The following code works great of I want to dynamically build an orderby:

```
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderByAnyField<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty, bool desc, Type propertyType)
    {
        string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
                                      source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
    }
```

So, I want to be able to change the CAST of the sort. So, as an example, I would like to take:

```
    .OrderBy(x => x.Something)
```

and do this instead:

```
    .OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Something))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: When linq already gives you the functionality to sort on any property, then what are to trying to achieve here?

Comment: I need to dynamically sort by a passed column name. I also need to "cast" the column. So, I'm using the above code to sort by a passed column name. (i.e. .OrderByAnyField(passedColumnName, false, typeof(double)) ). passedColumnName could be the name of any column in the source.

Comment: Let me add to my comment, for clarity. I can sort by the column, same as .OrderBy(x => x.Something). I would like to sort by casting to a different datatype, like .OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Something)). If I try and use a different datatype, in resultExpression, I get an error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing one simpler approach to do the same. You can add generics as per your requirement. You can play on data any way you want

```
static object GetOrder(Table tb, string propertyName, bool desc)
{
    if (desc)
        return 0;

    PropertyInfo pI = typeof(Table).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var val = pI.GetValue(tb);
    return val;
}

static object GetOrderDesc(Table tb, string propertyName, bool desc)
{
    if (!desc)
        return 0;

    PropertyInfo pI = typeof(Table).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var val = pI.GetValue(tb);
    return val;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool desc = false;

    List<Table> table = new List<Table>() {
            new Table() { ID = "03", X = "Str1", Y = "C1", P = 10 },
            new Table() { ID = "04", X = "Str1", Y = "C1", P = 5 },
            new Table() { ID = "05", X = "Str1", Y = "C1", P = 1 },
            new Table() { ID = "06", X = "Str1", Y = "C1", P = 2 },
            new Table() { ID = "07", X = "Str2", Y = "C1", P = 25 },
            new Table() { ID = "08", X = "Str2", Y = "C1", P = 4 },
            new Table() { ID = "09", X = "Str1", Y = "C2", P = 411 },
            new Table() { ID = "10", X = "Str1", Y = "C2", P = 2356 },
            new Table() { ID = "11", X = "Str2", Y = "C2", P = 12 },
            new Table() { ID = "12", X = "Str2", Y = "C2", P = 33 },
        };

    var sortedTable = table.OrderBy(x => GetOrder(x, "P", desc)).OrderByDescending(x => GetOrderDesc(x, "P", desc));
}
```